# When i press back my image is getting uploaded to the db twice (php, sql)

Tags: php, html, image, mysqli

On my site users can upload a pic to a gallery from the gallery page(gallery.php)
When the form is submitted the user is redirected back to gallery.php where there image will now be part of the gallery. When this happens if the user presses back the image is then uploaded again to the server and the image is duplicated in the gallery.

This is the php and form code that run

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    $image = date(U).$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $target = "gallery_images/".$image;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `images` (username, image) VALUES ('$username', '$image')";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target);
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    header("location:gallery.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When user click previous page, some browser sends the previous POST again to the server.

You can assign a session cookie for every user with `session_start();`, then use random number generating code to assign a random variable with `$A_randomo_var` for each session. Every time a successfully POST action causes `$A_randomo_var` changes its value . Then add a invisible post parameter in the html , input randomvar=123asdfsf(note:123asdfsf changes in the html after a successful upload ) something like that.

then use `if( $_POST['randomvar'] == $A_randomo_var)`

if the random variable does not match, dont copy the file.